# How to pass a specific marker in Android Google Maps as an argument

Tags: android, google-maps, if-statement, marker

in my MapsActivity.java I've declared these 3 markers:

```
    final Marker ms9 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(moltkeStrasse9).title("Moltkestraße 9").snippet("Jetzt frei (hier klicken)")); ms9.showInfoWindow();
    final Marker ms27 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(moltkeStrasse27).title("Moltkestraße 27").snippet("Jetzt frei"));
    final Marker waa13 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(willyAndreasAllee13).title("Willy Andreas Allee 13").snippet("Jetzt frei"));
```

now when I click on of these InfoWindows I want to display a View with details about this location

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            if (marker == waa13) {
                Intent openDetailansichtWaa13 = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DetailansichtWaa13.class);
                startActivity(openDetailansichtWaa13);

            } else if (marker == ms27) {
                Intent openDetailansichtMs27 = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DetailansichtMs27.class);
                startActivity(openDetailansichtMs27);

            } else {
                Intent openDetailansichtMs9 = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,DetailansichtMs9.class);
                startActivity(openDetailansichtMs9);
            }
        }
    });
```

but the problem is that it open always the View `openDetailansichtMs9` (the last one in my if-else statement) 
Do I compare the markers false ?
Thanks for help

Comment: @Daniel Nugent thank you very much I didn't see the another question